# Retain pandas dataframe where column names not in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new dataframe to store columns of `all_kirpII_rna` dataframe where the column names are NOT in the `mrna_cimp` dataframe.

```
mrna_NONCIMP_df = all_kirpII_rna[all_kirpII_rna.columns.isin(mrna_cimp.columns) == "False"]
```

Traceback:

```
KeyError: False
```

Comment: Try `all_kirpII_rna[[col for col in all_kirpII_rna.columns if col not in mrna_cimp.columns]]`. If that does not address your question, please provide example data of your input dataframes and what dataframe you expect.

Comment: Thanks but I want the columns NOT in the other dataframe.

Comment: I just edited my comment, it just requires `not in` instead of `in`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"False"` is a string, not a boolean.  And if you have a list of booleans you can mask with them directly

You want something like

`mrna_NONCIMP_df = all_kirpII_rna.loc[:,~all_kirpII_rna.columns.isin(mrna_cimp.columns)]`